# Make ASP.NET WebSite Run in Compatibility View

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ie-compatibility-mode

Is there any way for an ASP.NET web-site to run automatically in compatibility view?

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do this by adding meta tag in your application header, if you using master pages then you don't need to add to every page.
    
         or
         

To set compatibility mode you can read this article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321432.aspx

Comment: When including a link always include the relevant portion in the answer in case the link goes dead later.